# CopyPNGFile Error When Archiving Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6.1

When I am archiving my project, I receive a CopyPNGFile error in Xcode 6.1. I have checked previous solutions posted on here and did not work for me. I checked for duplicate copies of the file that is mentioned and there are none. Also, I have also checked and confirmed the file is in correct .png format. I have also replaced the graphic file to be sure it is not corrupted.

The weird thing is I was able to archive this without any error before integrating HeyZap and the 64bit support for this game. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually this means either 1. your PNG file is corrupted somehow 2. your PNG file path is wrong (in which case you can delete the resource and add it again).